# SOAP - response XML unique tag

Tags: java, iphone, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am creating the web-service with the use of SOAP & WSDL. After creating WSDL I am generating the "Java bean skeleton" using eclipse. From the generated stubs I can able to call the web-service from IOS app.
In the web-service response I am returning the complex data type to the user. The problem is, 
**I am getting the unique response tag for the complex type as given below.**

**My WSDL is,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://service.cmp.app.com" xmlns:intf="http://service.cmp.app.com" xmlns:tns1="http://request.cmp.app.com" xmlns:tns2="http://response.cmp.app.com" xmlns:tns3="http://bean.cmp.app.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://service.cmp.app.com">
    <!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4 Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 
        PDT) -->
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://service.cmp.app.com">
            <import namespace="http://response.cmp.app.com"/>
            <import namespace="http://request.cmp.app.com"/>
            <import namespace="http://bean.cmp.app.com"/>
            <element name="ViewAppTrack">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="ViewAppTrackRequest" type="tns1:ViewAppTrackRequest"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="ViewAppTrackResponse">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="ViewAppTrackResponseReturn" type="tns2:ViewAppTrackResponse"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <complexType name="ArrayOf_tns3_MonthListBO">
                <sequence>
                    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="monthListItem" type="tns3:MonthListBO"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="ArrayOf_tns3_TaskListBO">
                <sequence>
                    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="taskListItem" type="tns3:TaskListBO"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://request.cmp.app.com">
            <import namespace="http://response.cmp.app.com"/>
            <import namespace="http://service.cmp.app.com"/>
            <import namespace="http://bean.cmp.app.com"/>
            <complexType name="ViewAppTrackRequest">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="userId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://bean.cmp.app.com">
            <import namespace="http://response.cmp.app.com"/>
            <import namespace="http://service.cmp.app.com"/>
            <import namespace="http://request.cmp.app.com"/>
            <complexType name="MonthListBO">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="date" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="lockStatus" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="dailyTime" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="taskListNew" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_tns3_TaskListBO"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="TaskListBO">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="trackId" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <element name="taskId" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <element name="trackDate" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://response.cmp.app.com">
            <import namespace="http://service.cmp.app.com"/>
            <import namespace="http://request.cmp.app.com"/>
            <import namespace="http://bean.cmp.app.com"/>
            <complexType name="ViewAppTrackResponse">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="monthBO" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_tns3_MonthListBO"/>
                    <element name="userId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="projectId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="customerId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="ViewAppTrackRequest">

        <wsdl:part element="impl:ViewAppTrack" name="parameters">

        </wsdl:part>

    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="ViewAppTrackResponse">

        <wsdl:part element="impl:ViewAppTrackResponse" name="parameters">

        </wsdl:part>

    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="AppWeb">

        <wsdl:operation name="ViewAppTrack">

            <wsdl:input message="impl:ViewAppTrackRequest" name="ViewAppTrackRequest">

            </wsdl:input>

            <wsdl:output message="impl:ViewAppTrackResponse" name="ViewAppTrackResponse">

            </wsdl:output>

        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="AppWebSoapBinding" type="impl:AppWeb">

        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="ViewAppTrack">

            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

            <wsdl:input name="ViewAppTrackRequest">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

            </wsdl:input>

            <wsdl:output name="ViewAppTrackResponse">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

            </wsdl:output>

        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="AppWebService">

        <wsdl:port binding="impl:AppWebSoapBinding" name="AppWeb">

            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/test/services/AppWeb"/>

        </wsdl:port>

    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

**And my request XML is,**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.cmp.app.com" xmlns:req="http://request.cpm.app.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:ViewAppTrack>
         <ser:ViewAppTrackRequest>
            <req:userId>5</req:userId>
         </ser:ViewAppTrackRequest>
      </ser:ViewAppTrack>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**The following response I am getting,**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ViewAppTrackResponse xmlns="http://service.cmp.app.com">
         <ViewAppTrackResponseReturn>
            <ns1:monthBO xmlns:ns1="http://response.cmp.app.com">
               <monthListItem>
                  <ns2:date xmlns:ns2="http://bean.cmp.app.com">1-2-2014, Saturday (nonworking day)</ns2:date>
                  <ns3:lockStatus xmlns:ns3="http://bean.cmp.app.com">N</ns3:lockStatus>
                  <ns4:dailyTime xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns4="http://bean.cmp.app.com"/>
                  <ns5:taskListNew xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns5="http://bean.cmp.app.com"/>
               </monthListItem>
               <monthListItem>
                  <ns6:date xmlns:ns6="http://bean.cmp.app.com">2-2-2014, Sunday (nonworking day)</ns6:date>
                  <ns7:lockStatus xmlns:ns7="http://bean.cmp.app.com">N</ns7:lockStatus>
                  <ns8:dailyTime xmlns:ns8="http://bean.cmp.app.com">04:00</ns8:dailyTime>
                  <ns9:taskListNew xmlns:ns9="http://bean.cmp.app.com">
                     <taskListItem>
                        <ns9:trackId>1070</ns9:trackId>
                        <ns9:taskId>14</ns9:taskId>
                     </taskListItem>
                     <taskListItem>
                        <ns9:trackId>1094</ns9:trackId>
                        <ns9:taskId>44</ns9:taskId>
                     </taskListItem>
                  </ns9:taskListNew>
               </monthListItem>
               <monthListItem>
                  <ns10:date xmlns:ns10="http://bean.cmp.app.com">3-2-2014, Monday</ns10:date>
                  <ns11:lockStatus xmlns:ns11="http://bean.cmp.app.com">N</ns11:lockStatus>
                  <ns12:dailyTime xmlns:ns12="http://bean.cmp.app.com">08:00</ns12:dailyTime>
                  <ns13:taskListNew xmlns:ns13="http://bean.cmp.app.com">
                     <taskListItem>
                        <ns13:trackId>1071</ns13:trackId>
                        <ns13:taskId>14</ns13:taskId>
                     </taskListItem>
                     <taskListItem>
                        <ns13:trackId>1073</ns13:trackId>
                        <ns13:taskId>44</ns13:taskId>
                       </taskListItem>
                  </ns13:taskListNew>
               </monthListItem>
            </ns1:monthBO>
            <ns14:userId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns114="http://response.cmp.app.com"/>5</ns14:userId>
         </ViewAppTrackResponseReturn>
      </ViewAppTrackResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem:
    I am getting the above XML response as same tag like monthListItem, taskListItem.

> ```
> (i.e,) monthBO -> 
>         monthListItem -> taskListItem, taskListItem, etc..., 
>         monthListItem -> taskListItem, taskListItem, etc...,
>         monthListItem -> taskListItem, taskListItem, etc...,
>         etc...
> ```

**Can I change the response like below. So that I can parse this response from IOS.**

> ```
> (i.e,) monthBO -> 
>         monthListItem1 -> taskListItem1, taskListItem2 
>         monthListItem2 -> taskListItem3, taskListItem4
>         monthListItem3 -> taskListItem5, taskListItem6
>         etc...
> ```

**Or is it possible to parse the complex type response data in IOS?**

Comment: can you please show backEnd code ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your desired output. You want to have a different namespace for each `monthListItem` and its contained `taskListItem`s although `monthListItem` is probably defined in `http://response.cmp.app.com` and `taskListItem` in `http://bean.cmp.app.com`. If ns9, ns10 or ns11 should be the month the `monthListItem` should be for, better define an attribute and set the month there

Comment: @RomanVottner: Thanks for the reply. No I don't want with different namespace. I have edited my question. Please check the topic "Can I change the response like below. So that I can parse this response from IOS." Can I get the response like this?

Comment: Unless you change either the schema-definitions itself and therefore the syntax the response returns or you transform the received response using XSLT into your desired format I doubt that this will be easily achievable.

Comment: @RomanVottner: Can u tell where should I change in the above wsdl?